# Define a syntax region which depends on the indentation level

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, vim-syntax-highlighting, viml

I'm trying to built a lighter syntax file for reStructuredText in Vim.  In rst, literal blocks start when "::" is encountered at the end of a line:

```
I'll show you some code::

    if foo = bar then
        do_something()
    end

Literal blocks end when indentation level is lowered.
```

But, literal blocks can be inside other structures that are indented but not literal:

```
.. important::


    Some code for you inside this ".. important" directive::

        Code comes here

    Back to normal text, but it is indented with respect to ".. important".
```

So, the problem is: how to make a region that detects the indentation?  I did that with the following rule:

```
syn region rstLiteralBlock  start=/^\%(\.\.\)\@!\z(\s*\).*::$/ms=e-1 skip=/^$/ end=/^\z1\S/me=e-1
```

It works pretty fine but has a problem: any match or region that appear in line that should be matched by "start" takes over the syntax rules.  Example:

```
Foo `this is a link and should be colored`_.  Code comes here::
```

It will not make my rule work because there is a "link" rule that takes over the situation.  This is because the `ms` and `me` matching parameters but I cannot take them off, because it would just color the whole line.

Any help on that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By matching the text before the `::` as the region's start, you're indeed preventing other syntax rules from applying there. I would solve this by *positive lookbehind*; i.e. only assert the rules for the text before the `::`, without including it in the match. With this, you even don't need the `ms=e-1`, as the only thing that gets matched for the region start is the `::` itself:

```
syn region rstLiteralBlock  start=/\%(^\%(\.\.\)\@!\z(\s*\).*\)\@<=::$/ skip=/^$/ end=/^\z1\S/me=e-1
```

The indentation will still be captured by the `\z(...\)`.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you very much for your answer, it solved the problem! But I found a simpler rule, that takes the indentation level of the code block into account and not the block that owns it. See: `start=/::\n\+\z(\s\+\)\S/ skip=/^\%(\z1\S\|^$\)/ end=/^\z1\@!.*/me=s-1`. Thanks!