# Keyword in Vim syntax region pattern

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to more or less reproduce for Python the `if0` syntax highlighting of C-like files in Vim where code surrounded by `#if 0` and `#endif` are grayed out (highlighted as `Comment`).
Instead of preprocessor directives, I would like to gray out Python code blocks starting with `if 0:` or `if False:`.

Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33907858/define-a-syntax-region-which-depends-on-the-indentation-level), I came up with the following code which almost works:

```
syn region pyIfFalse start=/^\(\s*\)if \%(0\+\|False\):\n\+\z(\1\s\+\)\S/ skip=/^\%(\z1\S\|^$\)/ end=/^\z1\@!.*/me=s-1
hi def link pyIfFalse Comment
```

This results in the following

```
 if 0: # grayed out (there is a space at the beginning)
   pass
if 0: # not grayed out
  pass
```

If I replace all `if` by `ef` (in the example and in the pattern), both blocks will be grayed out, meaning that the problem must be with the keyword `if`.

Following [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/675994/vim-region-with-keywords-in-syntax-patterns), one can redefine `if` as a `keyword contained` but then it would not be highlighted in regular text so it does not seem like a satisfying solution.

What is quite surprising to me is that the highlighting works for the first block but not the second, with the only difference being a space before the `if`.

Comment: As a follow-up, it would be great to be able to detect `if 1: ... else: ...` as is done currently done for C-like files but I feel like Python's indentation rules would make it much more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in `:help syn-priority`.

> 1. When multiple Match or Region items start in the same position, the item    defined last has priority.
> 2. A Keyword has priority over Match and Region items.
> 3. An item that starts in an earlier position has priority over items that    start in later positions.

In the third line of the example, the Keyword had priority over the Region (2.) but in the first line, the Region had priority because it started earlier (3.).

A workaround, for lack of a better alternative, is to downgrade the highlighting of `if` to a Match defined before the Region (1.).

```
syn clear pythonConditional
syn keyword pythonConditional elif else
syn match pythonIf /\<if\>/
syn region pyIfFalse start=/^\(\s*\)if \%(0\+\|False\):\n\+\z(\1\s\+\)\S/ skip=/^\%(\z1\S\|^$\)/ end=/^\z1\@!.*/me=s-1
hi def link pythonConditional  Conditional
hi def link pythonIf  Conditional
hi def link pyIfFalse Comment
```